# Ubuntu version update error with Docker and ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: ubuntu, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to understand why I can't do an upgrade of Ubuntu versions on the given Elastic Beanstalk [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html) with Docker.

This works fine:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx zip curl

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN curl -o /usr/share/nginx/www/master.zip -L https://codeload.github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/zip/master
RUN cd /usr/share/nginx/www/ && unzip master.zip && mv 2048-master/* . && rm -rf 2048-master master.zip

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

This doesn't:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx zip curl

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN curl -o /usr/share/nginx/www/master.zip -L https://codeload.github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/zip/master
RUN cd /usr/share/nginx/www/ && unzip master.zip && mv 2048-master/* . && rm -rf 2048-master master.zip

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-c", "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
```

The log file gives an: "returned a non-zero code: 127" error.

Comment: Did you see any message referring to the device mapper? Seems there is rather some discussion on GitHub Docker about Error 127 in that context.

Comment: Hi @Armand can you give me a hint where to find find this? (new to Docker...)

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5684#issuecomment-69052334

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command is failing because there is no `/usr/share/nginx/www` directory in container, but there is `/usr/share/nginx/html`

```
 ---> 1911c575617e
Step 4 : RUN curl -o /usr/share/nginx/www/master.zip -L https://codeload.github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/zip/master
 ---> Running in d0ad1a5e7a3f
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file /usr/share/nginx/www/master.zip: No such
Warning: file or directory
  0  324k    0   867    0     0   1969      0  0:02:48 --:--:--  0:02:48  1965
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 867)
INFO[0000] The command [/bin/sh -c curl -o /usr/share/nginx/www/master.zip -L https://codeload.github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/zip/master] returned a non-zero code: 23
$ docker run --rm -ti 1911c575617e
root@bfb101f5de87:/# ls -al  /usr/share/nginx/www
ls: cannot access /usr/share/nginx/www: No such file or directory
root@bfb101f5de87:/# ls -al  /usr/share/nginx
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May 23 11:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 65 root root 4096 May 23 11:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May 23 11:04 html
```

Tips: [Best practice](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) is to use the same run command for `apt-get update && apt-get install`. Also always try to delete temporary files in the same run command when they created: each run command create additional image, so if you get file in one run command and delete in the next one - it will be only marked as deleted, but it will unnecessary increase image size. In most of my images I use single run command which for ubuntu/debian looks like:

```
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections \
 && apt-get update -qq \
 && apt-get install -y -qq ... \
 ...
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```